Weblogic server data-source issue
I installed oracle weblogic server 10.3.6 and set up my data-source successfully but when I opened eclipse and added the server it always gives the error in the screenshot-1...from this point I tried removing the data-source and enter it again it always fails to connect in the test configuration step as screenshot-2 although the db credentials are correct...could anyone help ?
eclipse-error:
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.OracleDS' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/OracleDS'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:247)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:412)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.ehis.eslp.ServiceLocator.getDataSource(ServiceLocator.java:180)
    at com.ehis.eslp.ServiceLocator.getConnection(ServiceLocator.java:388)
    at webbeans.eCommon.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:83)
    at eMR.smrp.GeneratePD102$JobSchedulePD102.main(GeneratePD102.java:890)
    at eMR.smrp.GeneratePD102.init(GeneratePD102.java:35)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1981)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1955)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)


wls-admin-console-error:
Connection test failed.
Message icon - Error Could not establish a connection because of java.lang.NullPointerException<br/>weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:350)<br/>com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:734)<br/>com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:474)<br/>sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br/>sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)<br/>sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)<br/>java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)<br/>org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58)<br/>...


Tried to remove the data-source and re-enter it but the issue still presists.

Please copy or type the text into the question. Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

After some digging..it turned to be that I have duplicate ojdbc.jar versions in my classpath environment variables.
